# Calculate the difference between the largest and smallest column for each row

Tags: r, dataframe, difference

The title is pretty straight forward - how can I calculate the difference between the largest and smallest value column-wise, for each row?

Let's assume this is my data:

```
a b c d
1 2 3 4
0 3 6 9
3 2 1 4
9 8 7 6
```

For each row, I want to find the difference between the column with the highest value and the column with the lowest value - the result looks like this:

```
3
9
3
3
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1**

For each row (using `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`), use `range` to obtain a vector of the minimum and maximum value and then `diff` to obtain a difference of those values

```
apply(X = df, MARGIN = 1, function(x) diff(range(x)))
#[1] 3 9 3 3
```

**2**

If you want speedier solution, you can use parallel maxima and minima (`pmax` and `pmin`)

```
do.call(pmax, df) - do.call(pmin, df)
#[1] 3 9 3 3
```

---

**Data**

```
df = structure(list(a = c(1L, 0L, 3L, 9L), b = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 8L), 
    c = c(3L, 6L, 1L, 7L), d = c(4L, 9L, 4L, 6L)), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

**Timings**

```
dat <- df[sample(1:4,5e6,replace=TRUE),]
rw <- seq_len(nrow(dat))

system.time({
    apply(X = dat, MARGIN = 1, function(x) diff(range(x)))
})
#STILL RUNNING...

system.time({
    rw <- seq_len(nrow(dat))
    dat[cbind(rw, max.col(dat))] - dat[cbind(rw, max.col(-dat))]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.48    0.11    3.59 

system.time(do.call(pmax, dat) - do.call(pmin, dat))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.23    0.00    0.26 

identical(do.call(pmax, dat) - do.call(pmin, dat),
      dat[cbind(rw, max.col(dat))] - dat[cbind(rw, max.col(-dat))])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Did I mention that your answer was fast?

Comment: @Provisional.Modulation - on a small dataset it will be fast, try it on a big dataset >1M rows and I think it will slow significantly. It's a perfectly fine solution though.

Comment: I received an answer really quickly, and yes, this code would be really slow on a larger dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt using my old favourite `max.col` with a bit of matrix indexing:

```
rw <- seq_len(nrow(dat))
dat[cbind(rw, max.col(dat))] - dat[cbind(rw, max.col(-dat))]
#[1] 3 9 3 3
```

This should be much faster on large datasets, as per:

```
# 5 million big enough?
dat <- dat[sample(1:4,5e6,replace=TRUE),]

system.time({
  rw <- seq_len(nrow(dat))
  dat[cbind(rw, max.col(dat))] - dat[cbind(rw, max.col(-dat))]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.43    0.20    2.63 

system.time({
  apply(X = dat, MARGIN = 1, function(x) diff(range(x)))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  94.91    0.17   95.16
```